# Windows 10 Dell PC loses internet

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

My Dell Windows 10 PC every week or so will lose internet connection gradually. It starts by losing external access when connected to company VPN and then becomes total loss of access to anything external.

I can still access my local lan and all other systems function fine, just this PC. A reboot sorts the issue.

I've tried resetting my routes, disable/enable NIC, connected a USB NIC (first time connected) same effect.

I can ping 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 but cannot do DNS lookups to them, or my local DNS server but I can SSH to local DNS server. Other systems can do all of this.

**UPDATE: Started happening again!!**

I eventually found the problem to this one, there was some command I could run (pretty sure it was netstat) that returned a process that had a high queue number or something. And if my memory is correct, killing that process would resolve the issue.

Trouble is, it stopped happening. Not sure now if it was a rebuild or what, but it has started happening again and I want to find the original issue but cannot. Anyone got any ideas from my update?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is this a rebuild candidate?

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`